# Angular/RxJS JSON merge issue

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I'm working on an Angular app and one of the service I've created. How to combine these two JSON objects ?

JSON 1:

```
{
  "level1": {
    "level2": {
      "level31": "Text 1",
      "level32": "Text 2",
      "level33": "Text 3",
      "level34": "Text 4",
      "level35": "Text 5",
    }
  }
}
```

JSON 2:

```
{
  "level1": {
    "level2": {
      "level33": "Different Text 3",
    }
  }
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{
  "level1": {
    "level2": {
      "level31": "Text 1",
      "level32": "Text 2",
      "level33": "Different Text 3",
      "level34": "Text 4",
      "level35": "Text 5",
    }
  }
}
```

Regards,
HP

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use `deepmerge`. It is highly popular library that will serve your exact use case:

**Installation**

```
npm install deepmerge
```

**Usage**

```
import * as merge from 'deepmerge'

const result = merge(json1, json2)
```

Comment: Will I be able to use deepmerge with Observables as well?